# Pass DoubleArray from the object of one activity to another

Tags: android, bundle

i would like to send the values from one activity to another but i got null in the second activity please solve my problem.the first activity contains blog_info the details of that
blog is send to second activity based on these values the second activity search places .

```
final ArrayList<Blog> blogList = (ArrayList<Blog>) message
                .getResultList("Blog");
        for (Blog blog : blogList) {
            int i=0;
                latitude_Array[i] = Double.parseDouble(blog.getLatitude_zzs());
                longitude_Array[i]=Double.parseDouble(blog.getLongitude_zzs());
                i++;
        }
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_top_map_list);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            MainActivity_MapList.class);
                    //The method putDoubleArray(String, double[]) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, Double[])
                    bundle.putDoubleArray("latitude_Array", latitude_Array);

                    // intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

i have used a series of method such as :

bundle.putDoubleArray(key, value)

bundle.putSparseParcelableArray(key, value)

bundle.putParcelableArray(key, value)

bundle.putSerializable(key, value)

but i just get 'null' or '0.0' in the second activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, in the code you posted, you are putting an arraylist of lists of doubles, but then casting it to an arraylist of ? extends parcelable. those aren't the same type.

i assume you just want to pass a list (or array) of doubles. you can either use `putDoubleArray()` or `putSerializable()`. if you want to deal with an array of doubles, you need to have your doubles in a `double[]`, like,

```
double[] doubles = ...; // whatever
bundle.putDoubleArray(key, doubles);
```

to get them out on the other side,

```
double[] doubles = bundle.getDoubleArray(key);
```

if you want to pass your doubles in an array list, you must have your doubles in an `ArrayList<? implements Serializable>` ... e.g., `ArrayList<Double>`. like this,

```
ArrayList<Double> doubles = ...; // whatever
bundle.putSerializable(key, doubles);
```

to get them out of the bundle on the other side,

```
ArrayList<Double> doubles = (ArrayList<Double>)bundle.getSerializableExtra(key);
```

Comment: I have used your method but have a new fault. I want to know how to get the  doubleArray information in the "for(Blog blog:bloglist) "  and give it to bundle//The method putDoubleArray(String, double[]) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, Double[])

Comment: i have changed the question .because the website can not add new question follow your answer.

Comment: if you have a new question, you should post it in a new post.

Comment: Post it to a new post ,you will can not find it .I do not think the website is well in this point.[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642513/how-to-copy-the-latitude-from-forblog-blogbloglist-to-latitude-array